# DI MVC 6 - register Generics

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried following using [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) like suggested [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/322):

```
   services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblies(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).Assembly)
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)))
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithScopedLifetime());
```

and it didn't register any QueryHandler. But for commands

```
   services.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblies(typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly)
        .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithScopedLifetime());
```

it works. Did I something wrong? I've tried following:

```
var queryTypes = typeof(IQuery<>)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo() != null
                && !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface && !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract
                && t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i.Name.Equals("IQuery`1")));

    var handlerTypes = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.GetTypeInfo() != null && !t.GetTypeInfo().IsInterface
                && !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract
                && t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i.Name.Equals("IQueryHandler`2")));

    var closedHandlers = queryTypes.Select(t => typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(t, t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.First().GenericTypeArguments[0]));

    foreach (var closedHandler in closedHandlers)
    {
        // services.AddTransient(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), closedHandler);
        var implementation = handlerTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i.FullName.Equals(closedHandler.FullName)));
        if (implementation != null)
        {
            // services.AddTransient(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), implementation);
            services.AddTransient(closedHandler, implementation);
        }
    }
```

and in the services collcetion It seems to be right, but resolve crashes. Is this possible without using some 3rd party container? Thx

UPDATE#1:

for now it works updating the foreach to:

```
foreach (var closedHandler in closedHandlers)
        {
            // services.AddTransient(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), closedHandler);
            var implementation = handlerTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces.Any(i => i.FullName.Equals(closedHandler.FullName)));
            var imp = implementation.MakeGenericType(closedHandler.GenericTypeArguments[0], closedHandler.GenericTypeArguments[1]);
            if (implementation != null)
            {
                // services.AddTransient(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), implementation);
                services.AddTransient(closedHandler, imp);
            }
        }
```

but it strictly has to implement just those interfaces with that exact generic arguments count. I will try to find the better way, thx anyway

Comment: Why do you want to use the built-in DI container for this? The command/handler and query/handler abstractions are valuable because they make it easy to apply cross-cutting concerns using decorators, but it is impossible to apply decorators using the built-in DI container. I would suggest switching to Simple Injector, Autofac or StructureMap.

Comment: On other projects i'm using SimpleInjector, but for this specific one they doesn't want too many dependencies on other frameworks/solutions. but I will probably have to use one